# How do I get my output panel back in Sublime Text (OSX)?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When I began ST there was a box at the bottom that provided feedback on my code. I've named that the output panel (please enlighten me if that is not the correct term for it)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrUw1.jpg

I must have changed a setting accidentally, because at some point I noticed it had disappeared.

[http://imgur.com/a/yAzY6](https://imgur.com/a/yAzY6)

Solutions tried:

1. Scrolling the mouse around the area at the bottom of the ST window to try find a bar to drag up, in the hope that would bring the output panel back into view.
2. Tools/Build Results/Show Build Results.
3. Clicking on the icon at the far left of the window's bottom panel, selecting "Build Results". There is a "Hide Panel" option too which I've selected. After I select this option the menu remains the same except that that option is no longer there. I can bring it back by selecting the "Build Results" option.
4. Dragging ST from the applications folder to the Trash, re-downloading the .dmg file from the Internet, and installing the program again.

PS: I've Googled and can't find anyone who has experienced a similar issue.

Comment: There should be a shortcut for it. Have you tried CTRL+`? (The backquote mark on the tilde key)

Comment: I just tried it. Nothing happened.

Comment: Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings, and search for "console". What does the setting line say?

Comment: How do I search? I looked through what's listed and couldn't see "console" anywhere.

Comment: Try adding this line: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },` to the Key Bindings settings page.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to add shortcuts. I pasted your line in between the square brackets in the tab on the right, clicked to close that tab, and saved the content when asked whether or not I'd like to save it before closing. I tried cmd+` afterwards, but the output panel didn't appear.

Comment: What is the name of the thing I'm trying to make reappear?

Comment: It's called the console panel. Have you tried changing the binding to "alt+backquote" or to something else?

Comment: I changed it to alt+backquote, but the panel it brings up is different to the one I'm trying to make appear. This appears http://imgur.com/a/nTDjQ. This is what I'm trying to make appear http://imgur.com/LLovw9B.

Comment: Oh.. so the panel you're looking for is not the console panel, but the output panel. Try adding this line then: `{ "keys": ["alt+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec", "toggle": true} }`

Comment: I saved it but it doesn't work. I tried saving it with shift+backquote and command+alt+backquote, but neither alternative binding worked either.

Comment: I added a detailed explanation in an answer.. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

In Sublime Text, you have the console panel (in which you can enter python commands) and output panels (which can be many).
The console panel is called `console` (and the default key to open it is **CTRL+`**), and one already existing output panel is called `output.exec` (which displays output from building code for example).

To toggle (open/close) a panel, you can bind it to a key:

- Open Sublime Key Binding Preferences
- In the User Settings file, add a line such as:
  `{ "keys": ["alt+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} }`
- Save the file, and try your new shortcut key.

Your User keybindings file should look something like this:

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec", "toggle": true} }
]
```

**Note 1**:  This is JSON so there must be a comma after each line except the final line.

**Note 2**: Be careful not to set a shortcut already used by your system (Mac OS X)

**Modifier Keys:**

- ctrl = Control key
- alt = Alt/Option key
- shift = Shift key
- super = Command key (or the windows key on MSWindows). It's the key next to the space key usually.

*You can see what panels are available by opening the console panel and typing `window.panels()`*

Comment: Thanks Frax. Your answer was informative, but I haven't solved the problem. I've tried using the code you provided ({ "keys": ["alt+backquote"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec", "toggle": true} }), and tried replacing alt+backquote with a few different key bindings, but none work. The fact that toggling it on and off, as well as selecting the "Hide Panel" and "Show Build Results" options, have no visible effects makes me think it may be minimized into invisibility.

Comment: I got it back. I removed ST from my mac again, but this time deleted the system files too. The output panel came with the reinstalled version of ST.

Answer (score 1):

Remove ST (including the system files), download and install again to restore default settings with an output panel.

(This worked for me because I have just started in ST. I imagine it would be an unsatisfactory solution for someone who has customised ST and doesn't want to return to the default settings.)